# Standard interface for a class being an algebraic structure

Tags: python, types, algebra, abc

Is there already any standard for an interface a Python class which is algebraic structure should implement? I want to make my code more generic.

For example, numbers and square matrices are both semigroups with multiplication and one. If they implement `.one()` method returning the identity element of `*`, I could implement exponentiation by squaring working for objects of both classes:

```
def exp_by_squaring(x, n):
    result = x.one() # <--
    while n > 0:
        if n % 2 == 1:
            result *= x
        x = x * x
        n = n // 2
    return result
```

Also, the function may work fine with objects of any class being a semigroup with multiplication and one (given the class implements such interface), no matter whether they are numeric or not.

I know, that I could introduce my own interface for that purpose (as I did in the example), but I would like to stick to existing solutions (if possible).

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html

Comment: The objects themselves don't have an identity, the group does.  What would you expect your function to return if you gave it an int object?  You don't know if you're looking for identity under multiplication or addition or some other operator.

Comment: @L-Jones9: I think not. Symbolic calculations are not what I have in mind. But thanks.

Comment: @Patrick Haugh: You are right, but since identity for '+' is traditionally 'zero', and for '*' - 'one', you may for example have a class attribute/method/property of such names.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to modify the builtins.  If you want to do that, the closest you can get is to make a wrapper class for them that has the attributes you want.  At that point it's probably easier to manually enter the  values

Comment: @Patrick Haugh: I know, they are builtins. The example was confusing, so I changed it to use a defined function.

Comment: any numeric object that supports the [`__add__` and `__mul__` etc.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) magic methods would be usable by that function.  there are tools to create [abstract classes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta) but I think I very much am not correctly understanding this question...

Comment: I think your best bet is using an existing symbolic math package.  When I took cryptography, we use Sage which I thought was very intuitive for abstract algebra. http://www.sagemath.org/

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen: the problem is that I want to be able to use the code for other objects, like square matrices etc. While the numeric API is well defined, I know no such standard for obtaining the identity element for `*`

Comment: if you start with `result = 1` then `exp_by_squaring(numpy.arange(12).reshape((3,4)), 3)` works fine, and will continue to work fine as long as the type of `x` supports being multiplied by itself and by 1.  Still don't quite understand what the issue is.

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen: thought about it, but for the boundary case `exp_by_squaring(x, 0)` it returns bad type.

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen: The issue is more general and may be solved by introducing my own protocol - but what I am asking, is whether there is already any standard API for that purpose.

Comment: ok I now understand what you are asking about - I am not aware of any standard api to get basically the equivalent to 1 for the specified type. Although you may want to rephrase your question to have less jargon if possible so that if someone does have the answer you are looking for they are more likely to identify that is what you are looking for.